# Prove $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3)$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

The title is all there is to the question. I'm not looking for a solution to the problem; my question is, why wouldn't the two be isomorphic in the first place? They are both finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ of dimension $2$. Shouldn't they be isomorphic?

This is out of Dummit and Foote, Section $14.1$ if that matters to anyone.

Comment: Isomorphic as field extensions, or isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Suppose that $\phi: \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$ is an isomorphism and let $c = \phi(\sqrt{2})$.  Then $c = a + b\sqrt{3}$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.  Try to come up with a contradiction - consider $c^2$...

Comment: @hardmath I guess isomorphic as field extensions; I've generally thought of the two as pretty much the same thing hence my confusion now.

Comment: @JairTaylor That helps, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is to show that they are not isomorphic as fields, not vector spaces. It is true that they are isomorphic vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ because they have the same dimension.

Comment: So, my confusion stemmed from the fact that I was thinking of these field extensions essentially as just vector spaces over the smaller field. Is the difference in structure arising from the fact that, when viewing as a field, I can multiply the generating elements together, while in a vector space that "operation" doesn't exist?

Comment: Exactly! An function from $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$ might be a linear bijection, and hence an isomorphism of vector spaces, but without respecting multiplication. For example, the function taking $a+b\sqrt{2}$ to $a+b\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Why not? The question posed in the OP wasn't to prove that they aren't isomorphic, but rather why the fact that they are of the same dimension doesn't imply that they are.

Comment: @user281392 I see now, thanks!

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD But it clearly did clear up the OP's confusion, which is quite admirable. I upvoted.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD his initial answer definitely wasn't the most thorough but his input and comment have definitely helped me understand so I'm giving him the credit for the answer.

Comment: @user281392 Precisely because of that. Saying "they're isomorphic as vector spaces but not as fields" doesn't answer it. I've removed my downvote, anyway.

Comment: One more question just out of curiosity if anyone is still reading this.. would a field isomorphism between the two (if it existed) be required to fix $\mathbb{Q}$? Since an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ would, I'm wondering if this extends to isomorphisms of fields.

Comment: @mathers101 Yes, any morphism of fields containing $\mathbb{Q}$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$.  This is because $\phi(1) = 1$, so $\phi(n) = \phi(1+\cdot + 1) = n\phi(1) = n$, and $\phi(m)\phi(1/m) = 1$ so $\phi(1/m) = 1/\phi(m) = 1/m$.

Comment: @Slade Ah yeah that's simple to show, I should have been able to figure that out. Thanks though

Answer (score 3):

Besides the brute-force approach of showing that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ has no square root of $3$, or showing that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$ has no square root of $2$, you could also take this approach:

Find a rational polynomial of degree $4$ with $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ as a root, and show that it's irreducible.  Then $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]$ has degree $4$.

Comment: Would you mind completing your answer, please?  I could find the irreducible polynomial... what next?

Comment: I guess I could figure it out. Since the degree was shown to be 4, we can deduce that de degree of $ Q(\sqrt 2+ \sqrt 3)  = Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$ over $Q(\sqrt 3)$ is 2. Therefore, $\sqrt2 \not \in Q (\sqrt3)$, because if it was we would find a polynomial of degree one realizing it, which contradicts the fact that the extension is of degree 2. Now apllying the trickery of a isomorphism, we would find $2 = \phi(\sqrt 2)^2$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

in $Q[\sqrt(3)]$ consider the integral closure of $Z$ ,  $5$ is  a prime.

In $Q[\sqrt(2)$, 5 is not a prime in the integral closure of $Z$

Comment: $2 = (\sqrt{2})^2$.  What it's not is unramified.